clearing the four least significant bits of mac address
I'm setting up virtual ssid's and came across this guide https://medium.com/@renaudcerrato/how-to-setup-a-virtual-ssid-with-hostapd-804c13c9a3c2 This part

clearing the four least significant bits and also setting the U/L bit

What method do they use to get mac 46:c3:06:00:03:e0 from the original one 44:c3:06:00:03:eb?

By setting the U/L 2 bytes to 0. 0x0b and 0x06. They could have cleared any part of the original MAC address.

How would i do this conversion in bash? i.e mac in > do bits > mac out

What research have you done? Doing bit operations seems like a trivial task. Your question made mention of bash. I personally won’t be coming back to this question, but a never ending moving if the goal post, isn’t going to result in a positive reaction

A MAC address is just six separate bytes, go learn some basic python and you will have tool to accomplish the above in about five minutes.
